# Telit HE910 Mini PCI - cdc-acm Errors

Tags: drivers, usb-modem, gammu

I'm new to ubuntu ;) and at the moment i'm facing the following Problem:

**Phonecalls with an Telit He910 Mini PCI chip via wammu/gammu**

at first it sounds easy but there are several errors i don't understand.

I'm having the latest Ubuntu version:

```
Linux ... 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:30:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When the system starts up i'm getting cdc-acm Error's:

```
[   11.388593] cdc_acm 1-5:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   11.388788] cdc_acm 1-5:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[   11.393612] cdc_acm 1-5:1.2: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   11.393765] cdc_acm 1-5:1.2: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[   11.396258] cdc_acm 1-5:1.4: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   11.396386] cdc_acm 1-5:1.4: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
[   11.398959] cdc_acm 1-5:1.6: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   11.399088] cdc_acm 1-5:1.6: ttyACM3: USB ACM device
[   11.402498] cdc_acm 1-5:1.8: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   11.402663] cdc_acm 1-5:1.8: ttyACM4: USB ACM device
[   11.404926] cdc_acm 1-5:1.10: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   11.405084] cdc_acm 1-5:1.10: ttyACM5: USB ACM device
[   11.407360] cdc_acm 1-5:1.12: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   11.407484] cdc_acm 1-5:1.12: ttyACM6: USB ACM device
```

my lsusb shows that the system detected the Telit Chip:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bc7:0021 Telit HE910
```

Starting Wammu and trying to connect the phone shows the following:

```
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: [Gammu            - 1.33.0 built 16:20:47 Aug  1 2013 using GCC 4.8]
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: [Connection       - "at115200"]
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: [Connection index - 0]
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: [Model type       - "at"]
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: [Device           - "/dev/ttyACM0"]
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: [Running on       - Linux, kernel 3.13.0-39-generic (#66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:30:27 UTC 2014)]
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: [Module           - "A2D|iPAQ|at|M20|S25|MC35|TC35|C35i|S65|S300|5110|5130|5190|5210|6110|6130|6150|6190|6210|6250|6310|6310i|6510|7110|8210|8250|8290|8310|8390|8850|8855|8890|8910|9110|9210"]
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: Serial device: DTR is up, RTS is up, CAR is down, CTS is up
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: Setting speed to 115200
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: Escaping SMS mode
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x02/2
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: 1B |0D                                                          ..              
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x03/3
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:08: 41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.             
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: 1 "AT+CPIN?"
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: 2 "+CPIN: READY"
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: 3 "OK"
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: Checking line: OK
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x1F/31
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|49I|4EN|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|50P|49I|4EN AT+CPIN?...+CPIN
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: 3A:|20 |52R|45E|41A|44D|59Y|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : READY....OK.. 
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: 
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: Frame not request now. If you can, please report it (see <http://wammu.eu/support/bugs/>). Thank you
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: LAST SENT frame type 0x00/length 3
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: 41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.             
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x1f/31
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|49I|4EN|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|50P|49I|4EN AT+CPIN?...+CPIN
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: 3A:|20 |52R|45E|41A|44D|59Y|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : READY....OK.. 
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:09: 
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:10: Enabling echo
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:10: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x05/5
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:10: 41A|54T|45E|311|0D                                              ATE1.           
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:13: Phone does not support enabled echo, it can not work with Gammu!
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:13: Init:Phone->Initialise failed with error TIMEOUT[14]: No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected.
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:13: Entering GSM_SetIncomingSMS
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:13: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x08/8
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:13: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D                                  AT+CGMI.        
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:16: [System error     - serial_read, 11, "Resource temporarily unavailable"]
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:17: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x05/5
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:17: 41A|54T|49I|333|0D                                              ATI3.           
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 1 "AT+CPMS="SM","SM""
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 2 "+CPMS: 0,30,0,30,0,30"
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 3 "OK"
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: Checking line: OK
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x31/49
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|4DM|53S|3D=|22"|53S|4DM|22"|2C,|22"|53S|4DM AT+CPMS="SM","SM
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 22"|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|50P|4DM|53S|3A:|20 |300|2C,|333|300|2C, "...+CPMS: 0,30,
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 300|2C,|333|300|2C,|300|2C,|333|300|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D  0,30,0,30....OK.
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 0A                                                              .               
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: Frame not request now. If you can, please report it (see <http://wammu.eu/support/bugs/>). Thank you
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: LAST SENT frame type 0x00/length 5
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 41A|54T|49I|333|0D                                              ATI3.           
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x31/49
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|4DM|53S|3D=|22"|53S|4DM|22"|2C,|22"|53S|4DM AT+CPMS="SM","SM
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 22"|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|50P|4DM|53S|3A:|20 |300|2C,|333|300|2C, "...+CPMS: 0,30,
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 300|2C,|333|300|2C,|300|2C,|333|300|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D  0,30,0,30....OK.
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 0A                                                              .               
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:18: 
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:21: Setting SMS memory type to ME
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:21: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0D/13
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:21: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|4DM|53S|3D=|22"|4DM|45E|22"|0D              AT+CPMS="ME".   
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: 1 "AT+CPIN?"
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: 2 "+CPIN: READY"
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: 3 "OK"
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: Checking line: OK
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x1F/31
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|49I|4EN|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|50P|49I|4EN AT+CPIN?...+CPIN
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: 3A:|20 |52R|45E|41A|44D|59Y|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : READY....OK.. 
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: 
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: Frame not request now. If you can, please report it (see <http://wammu.eu/support/bugs/>). Thank you
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: LAST SENT frame type 0x00/length 13
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|4DM|53S|3D=|22"|4DM|45E|22"|0D              AT+CPMS="ME".   
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x1f/31
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|49I|4EN|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|50P|49I|4EN AT+CPIN?...+CPIN
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22: 3A:|20 |52R|45E|41A|44D|59Y|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : READY....OK.. 
Tue 2014/11/04 01:35:22:
```

And last but not least the gammu config:

```
[gammu]

port = /dev/ttyACM0
model = at
connection = at115200
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = /tmp/gammu_log
logformat = textalldate
use_locking = no
gammuloc = 
name=
```

My thought is that there's an problem with the cdc-acm driver.
Did you have any ideas what can be else checked?

Br and many thx
Max